# Why does TS private constructor arg not result in 'this' context property? Works in examples! Is it TS version dependent? & what is VS Code fix about?

Tags: typescript, parameters, constructor, visual-studio-code, ionic3

I am doing this in the context of an Ionic 3 App and the constructor of a Page.

If I have code like so:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
const REFRESH = 'refresh';
export class JobsPage {
  constructor (private events:Events) {
    events.subscribe(REFRESH, ()=> {
      ...
    });
  }
  ionViewWillUnload():void {
    this.events.unsubscribe(REFRESH);
  }
}
```

VS Code provides a light bulb with a fix (this is not the same code as above... I abridged the solution but am showing the same issue with no `this.events` nonetheless and the context menu you gain accessibility to).

[image: VS Code add index signature]

If I select add index signature for property 'events', it adds the following code snippet, after `export class JobsPage {` and before the `constructor`.

```
[x: string]: any;
```

and the warnings disappear.

1. What exactly is that all about?
2. I know I can make the constructor argument for events public and gain accessibility to `this.events`, (no accessibility modifier denies this too - same as private. I could also declare a class property `private events2:Events` and in the constructor say `this.events2 = events`), but I have seen videos like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSk1STdGjrI)
   where it allowed private constructor argument and accessibility to this.events, per the following screenshot.

**Screenshot from linked Youtube video @4:51**

[image: this.events with private constructor]

Is this somehow down to a TypeScript version?

I am using:

- TypeScript 2.4.2
- VS Code (for Mac) Version 1.31.0

**TypeScript version I use taken from my VSCode IDE**

[image: Typescript Version]

**VS Code version for Mac**

[image: VS Code Version]

Comment: is TSLint extension installed on your VS Code ?

Comment: @CodeChanger - I thought it was - but no. (I have a VM where I also do Python Development - I had enabled some sort of linter for that environment - not the native OSX one where I use it for TypeScript)

Comment: Is the `[x:string]: any` perhaps a way of doing a map style property reference - that's sort of like late binding or run-time evaluation of type perhaps? So you could perhaps have `this.['events']`?